# Is possible to inject metadata into an AVURLAsset?

Tags: ios, avplayer, apple-tv, avasset

I'm playing live and ondemand HLS streams in AVPlayer using an AVURLAsset. Timed metadata is coming from a REST Webservice in separate call, but I need to inject those in the asset amnually. Since all metadata properties are getter-only, is possible to modify this parameter after its creation?